DropDownList closes immediatly after open in template in ListBox
I have two connected listboxes. First listbox has list of divs with unique dropdownlist in it.
I want have opportunity to select and change value in any of that dropdownlist and drag and drop one of this div with dropdownlist to other listbox.
I use demo from telerik as example https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/listbox/templates.
Drag and Drop is working, i fill first listbox with elements and even fill all dropdownlists with elements. Thats all works fine.
But when i open any of this dropdownlist, it immedidatly closes, and i can't select any value.
And i see, that all this dropdownlists is filled with correct data, i don't get any error in console, it just closes immediatly after opening by clickig on them.
But, if i dont use mouse and use only keyboard with tab and space buttons, i can open dropdownlist and select other value in it. But that's not how anyone want to work with it
This is my listboxes
<div id="example" >
        <div class="demo-section wide">
            @(Html.Kendo().ListBox()
            .Name("optional")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("SysName")
            .DataSource(source => source
                .Read(read => read.Action("FiltersList_Read", "Links"))
            )
            .TemplateId("customer-item-template")
            .Draggable(draggable => draggable.Placeholder("customPlaceholder"))
            .DropSources("selected")
            .ConnectWith("selected")
            .Toolbar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Position(Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ListBoxToolbarPosition.Right);
                toolbar.Tools(tools => tools
                    .MoveUp()
                    .MoveDown()
                    .TransferTo()
                    .TransferFrom()
                    .TransferAllTo()
                    .TransferAllFrom()
                    .Remove());
            })
        )
            @(Html.Kendo().ListBox()
            .Name("selected")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("SysName")
            .TemplateId("customer-item-template")
            .Draggable(draggable => draggable.Placeholder("customPlaceholder"))
            .DropSources("optional")
            .ConnectWith("optional")
            .BindTo(new List<FilterList>())
        )
        </div>
    </div>

That is my template for listitem
<script id="customer-item-template" type="text/kendo-template">
    <div>
        <span class="k-state-default"><h3>#: data.Name #</h3><p>#: data.SysName #</p></span>
        <div id="div_#=SysName#">
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("ddl_#=SysName#")
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("ItemId")
                    .DataSource(source => source
                        .Read(read => read.Action("Filter_Read", "Links", new { FilterSysName = "#=SysName#" }))
                    )
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
                    .Popup(x=>x.AppendTo("ddl_#=SysName#"))
                    .ToClientTemplate()
                )
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

I also uses all styles and some script from demo, but their do nothing to open/close operation (i disable them and nothing changed)
update: i change dropdownlist to multiselect and it has same problem

Do you have any client side code that is hooked to events on the dropdownlist? Also, that .Popup you have on the dropdownlist definition - I'm not seeing that in the docs for the Kendo DropDownList?

@G_P no, i have not any client code for this dropdownlists. .Popup is one of attributes of dropdownlists, which i try to use in order to find solution. But it didn't work at all

Ahh - I see popup in the documentation now. Curious why you have popup configured like that, to appendto the div that you have the dropdownlist created within. Does removing the Popup configuration change anything?
